# To make my code work I had to alter some core functionality of cheerio, how can I persist it in my module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, cheerio

Im creating a "web crawler" for learning purposes, and I had to change some cheerioJS core funcionality to make my code work, here is what happens:

index.js:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    module.exports.findWordInURL = function(url, word) {
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                $ = cheerio.load(body);
                texto = [];
                retorno = [];
                b = $('body').text().toLowerCase();
                c = b.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                texto = c.split("¬");
                for (var i = texto.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (texto[i].search(word) !== -1) {
                        retorno.push("+" + texto[i] + "+");
                    }
                }
                console.log(retorno);
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };
```

It only works because i have changed the "$().text()" function to fit my needs:

static.js from cheerio lib, look at the change inside >>> <<<:

```
/**
 * $.text(dom)
 */

exports.text = function(elems) {
  if (!elems) return '';

  var ret = '',
      len = elems.length,
      elem;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    elem = elems[i];
    if (elem.type === 'text') ret += elem.data >>>+ "¬"<<<;
    else if (elem.children && elem.type !== 'comment') {
      ret += exports.text(elem.children);
    }
  }

  return ret;
};
```

then, when I call it inside another .js file it works as expected:

teste.js:

```
var webCrawler = require('./index');

webCrawler.findWordInURL("http://www.estadao.com.br/","temer");
```

node teste.js:
[image]

How can I make my module go to NPM with this modified cheerio or at least if someone clone it on git, receive this modified cheerio when he installs it by npm install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**Method 1**

You could avoid modifying the original cheerio altogether by putting your modified cheerio.text function (not sure if it's cheerio.text, check) in your own index.js itself:

index.js

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

cheerio.text = function(elems) {
  if (!elems) return '';

  var ret = '',
      len = elems.length,
      elem;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    elem = elems[i];
    if (elem.type === 'text') ret += elem.data >>>+ "¬"<<<;
    else if (elem.children && elem.type !== 'comment') {
      ret += exports.text(elem.children);
    }
  }

  return ret;
};
```

This way at least we all `npm install` the same Cheerio and get your modified function if we use your app

---

**Method 2**

If you can't seem to do Method 1, you can always fork the module you're using to your Github, in this case https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Then you can modify as you please, push it to your Github, and then in your own `package.json`:

```
"cheerio": "github.com/<YOURNAME>/cheerio";
```

Of course, if you believe your edits would help improve the overall module, you can make a issue/PR at the original module then.

Comment: Omg! Great ideia, i will try to do it and post the results!

Comment: Oh. Well, you could then fork https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio, edit it as you wish, push it to your own github acct

Comment: then link it in package.json via "cheerio": "https://github.com/<YOURNAME>/cheerio"

Answer (score 0):

As user @vtange said:

> Oh. Well, you could then fork github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio, edit it as
>   you wish, push it to your own github acct          then link it in
>   package.json via "cheerio": "github.com/(YOURNAME)/cheerio".

It worked! NPM install, installed the forked version from my git!